# Gnuplot - function

Tags: math, graph, gnuplot

Why this graph doesn't go through `[0,0]`?

Why is `f(0) = 5`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gnuplot, the `/` operator with integer operands does integer division, like Python's `//` operator.  So your `5/3` exponent evaluates simply to `1`, and likewise `2/3` is `0`.

If you want a fractional answer, use floating-point arguments:

```
f(x)=2*x**(5.0/3.0) + 5*x**(2.0/3.0)
```

Comment: It's enough when one operand is float and one also omit the zero. So `5./3` and `2/3.` suffices (compactness vs. readability).